# Convert slice of struct to 2D slice of string

Tags: go

I want to take data from DB and write to excel

let's say I have a struct like:

```golang
type user struct {
    ID    int64
    Name  string
    Age   int
}
```

I can get a pointer to slice of user type form DB `&[]user{}`

but I want to convert that slice to a 2D slice of string `[][]string{}`

and here's my code try to do such job:

```golang
func toStrings(slice interface{}) [][]string {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(slice).Elem().Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        ret := [][]string{}
        val := reflect.ValueOf(slice).Elem()
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {

            tempSlice := []string{}

            tempV := reflect.ValueOf(val.Index(i))

            for j := 0; j < tempV.NumField(); j++ {
                tempSlice = append(tempSlice, tempV.Field(j).String())
            }

            ret = append(ret, tempSlice)
        }
        return ret
    }
    return nil

}
```

But from the code above all I get is a slice like `[<*reflect.rtype Value> <unsafe.Pointer Value> <reflect.flag Value>]`

where I do it wrong?

my codes in [golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cVAy76YUXrx)

Comment: Post a [mcve].  In particular, show an example of calling the function, actual results and expected results.

Comment: @CeriseLimón sorry, I've provided golang playground

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I found where I do it wrong, I got `tempV` wrong

```golang
func toStrings(slice interface{}) [][]string {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(slice).Elem().Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        ret := [][]string{}
        val := reflect.ValueOf(slice).Elem()
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {

            tempSlice := []string{}

            // tempV should be:
            tempV := val.Index(i)
            // instead of reflect.ValueOf(val.Index(i))

            for j := 0; j < tempV.NumField(); j++ {
                tempSlice = append(tempSlice, tempV.Field(j).String())
            }

            ret = append(ret, tempSlice)
        }
        return ret
    }
    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code in the question. The first problem is the slice element is doubled wrapped by a a reflect.Value in the expression `reflect.Value(val.Index(i))`.  Fix by removing the extra call to reflect.Value. The second problem is that the [reflect.Value String](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.String) method does not convert the underlying value to its string representation.  Use fmt.Sprint (or one of its friends) to do that.

Try this:

```
func toStrings(slice interface{}) [][]string {
    // Get reflect value for slice. Use Indirect to
    // handle slice argument and pointer to slice
    // argument.
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(slice))
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return nil
    }

    var result [][]string

    // For each element...
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {

        // Get reflect value for slice element (a struct). Use
        // Indirect to handle slice of struct and slice of
        // pointer to struct.
        e := reflect.Indirect(v.Index(i))
        if e.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
            return nil
        }

        // Convert fields to string and append.
        var element []string
        for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
            // Use fmt.Sprint to convert arbitrary Go value
            // to a string.
            element = append(element, fmt.Sprint(e.Field(i).Interface()))
        }

        result = append(result, element)
    }
    return result
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nTVWN28Jo5w).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a simple way to resolve the problem, [golang playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/3UYEuPRSBKx)

I used `encoding/json` to convert to json data, then convert it to map[string]interface{}.

```golang
func toStrings2(slice interface{}) [][]string {
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(slice)
    var out []map[string]interface{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &out)
    var fields []string
    if len(out) > 0 {
        for k := range out[0] {
            fields = append(fields, k)
        }
    }
    var ret [][]string
    for _, row := range out {
        var r []string
        for _, k := range fields {
            r = append(r, fmt.Sprint(row[k]))
        }
        ret = append(ret, r)
    }
    return ret
}
```

**Notice:**

With the help of @CeriseLimón, I known that the code in this answer can't handle large values for User.ID.

Comment: The code in this answer does not handle large values for User.ID.  An example that does not work is User.ID = 9223372036854775807.